# SCRUM - Sizing in sprint. Do I need to use story points in a sprint if the duration of the project phase itself is only 3-4 months?

Tags: scrum, story-points

In my current company, DSDM is being practiced.

For a new project that we are starting, there are no backlogs yet and it is decided we will be executing the project in sprints.

The duration of the project is about 3-4 months.

In this scenario, I believe using a different sizing (T-shirt sizing) should suffice.  I dont see a value in using story point estimation in this type of situation; eg. no velocity calculation required to forecast our deliverable for future or to calculate our productivity for the sprints.

The management would want to continue with Story points.

Please let us know how I can continue sizing stories.

Comment: Note - Plan is to go on a two-week sprint cycle.  Expected project duration is about 4 months - so the project itself will be over in a max of 8-10 sprints.

Comment: In this situation, why estimate at all?

Answer (score 1):

The team will be doing the estimating and the team will be doing the work. It would seem logical that the team should be the ones to decide which estimating units are most appropriate.

The only exception I can see to this is if your management are using story points as a cross-project metric. [However, it is usually a bad idea to compare story points across teams](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/is-it-a-good-idea-to-establish-a-common-baseline-for-story-points).

My suggestion would be to have an open discussion with your management about what they are trying to achieve and about the importance of empowering teams to make their own decisions.